# Losing sessions between two servlets localhost

Tags: java, session, servlets, fiddler

I am having a little problem here. We are a group of 3 guys developing a web application.. When I'm doing post to one servlet handling the login, and afterwards do a post to another servlet where I'm trying to use the attribute we've stored in the session in the Login, it's like it is using another session. I don't think there is a problem in the code, since the other guys can do this without any problems..

I'm using fiddler2 as my restclient, where the others are using Cocoa as their clients. When I'm inspecting the headers the two different posts is having two different session id's.

I've been trying to figure this out most of the day, but haven't found out of anything yet. I will be thankfull for any advise.

Comment: If the `sessionId` is different then the session is different, the key question appears to be *why* is the `sessionId` different?

Comment: are cookies  enabled?

Comment: Typically, requests are tied to a session via a cookie, like JSESSIONID. When a browser is the client program, it will handle storing and sending cookies coming from the web app for you, but if you're writing your own client, you'll have to handle cookies yourself (or use a library).

Comment: Exactly my thought Elliott, but I haven't figured it out yet.  Yes NobalG I have cookies enabled in Chrome. I'm not communicating with the server via the browser, but via Fiddler2 though. Is it in fiddler I have to handle the cookies maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fiddler's Composer does not attempt to maintain any sort of cookie jar for you. If you want to send a cookie on a request using the Composer, you must add it yourself. You will find the value in the `Set-Cookie` response header on a previous response.

Comment: This is the right answer, I just found out myself though. Thank you for your help!